# Cisco IOS password types - relative security

Tags: hash, passwords, pbkdf2, cisco-ios, scrypt

Cisco has finally gotten around to offering two relatively modern ways to store passwords in configuration files:

- PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 with 20,000 iterations
- Scrypt with N=16384, r=1, p=1

My question for the security gods is, given the two algorithms above: is one clearly better then the other, are they about the same, or are there any obvious tradeoff's that make it a hard decision?

Answer (score 0):

The Scrypt one is clearly better.

- PBKDF2 is using 20,000 iterations

But SHA256 is ***extraordinarily*** easy to compute. I own a 2.5W USB stick that on SHA256 can calculate 330 million hash/sec. (i have 14 of these usb sticks, for a total of 4.6 Thash/s

- Those Scrypt parameters are set to use:

  - 16,384 iterations
  - operating randomly on 2 MB of memory

Scrypt is very difficult to parallelize in hardware. The current [state of the art of scrypt hashing can do about 1.3 million hash/sec](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison), while consuming about 900W.

```
| Algorithm |  Power | Speed           | 
|-----------|--------|-----------------|
| PBKDF2    |   2.5W | 330,000,000 H/s |
| Scrypt    | 900W   |   1,300,000 H/s |
```